# ajax octobercms passing value of id

Tags: php, ajax, octobercms

```
 <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-small btn-danger icon-trash"
            data-request="onDeleteItem"
            data-control="popup"
            data-request-data="id: " <<<<<<<----
            data-trigger-action="enable"
            data-stripe-load-indicator>
</button>
```

in `Configurations.php::controller`

```
public function onDeleteItem()
```

how do i get the value of id in a list? I want to list of all configs in a table, have an custom column, Edit, Delete

i want to click delete, then it will delete the item, but how do i get the ID?

Answer (score 4):

I have used this (referenced from the RainLab.Blog plugin) and it works perfectly:

```
<button
    class="btn btn-default oc-icon-trash-o"
    disabled="disabled"
    onclick="$(this).data('request-data', {
        checked: $('.control-list').listWidget('getChecked')
    })"
    data-request="onDelete"
    data-request-confirm="Are you sure?"
    data-trigger-action="enable"
    data-trigger=".control-list input[type=checkbox]"
    data-trigger-condition="checked"
    data-request-success="$(this).prop('disabled', false)"
    data-stripe-load-indicator>
    Delete all selected
</button>
```

You can see that this uses jQuery in the `onClick` handler to get all checked Ids and passes it to the controller.

Then in your controller you can do this:

```
public function index_onDelete()
{
    if (($checkedIds = post('checked')) && is_array($checkedIds) && count($checkedIds)) {

        foreach ($checkedIds as $modelId) {
            if ((!$model = Model::find($modelId)))
                continue;

            $model->delete();
        }

        Flash::success('Successfully deleted those items.');
    }

    return $this->listRefresh();
}
```

Just make sure to replace `model` with your actual 'model'. The `index_` prefix on the controller method name ensures that we refer to `onDelete` in the index context (where the list of your models is displayed).

Comment: Your answer is good thanks. 
can you provide any documentation from where did you learn to index_ on controller ??

Answer (score 0):

If it's within a controller's action then

```
<?= $this -> id ?>
```

should work. Or else you can do something like

```
<?php
    $isDelete = $this->formGetContext() == 'delete';
?>
```

to initialize it and then use it as

```
data-request-data="id: <?= (int) $isDelete ?>"
```

As seen [here](https://github.com/feegleweb/oc-octoshoplite-plugin/blob/42b35c2186a566369cf0112ca6681a8030641054/controllers/products/_product_toolbar.htm#L11)

Comment: in OC, the index.htm is <?= $this->listRender() ?> for each item in list, there will be an ID. the list have multiple ids. how to properly reference it? [link](http://imgur.com/pBXQKQb)

Comment: Yes the ID is taken from the model that is related to the controller. A ListController is used here so it extends that class(https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/behaviors/ListController.php). You can use one of those public functions in that class to get the list data, including the IDs of the items

Comment: Alright. Good luck. Feel free to comment here if you face issues I'll help to fix it. I'm a plugin author anyway

Comment: Ah okay. Try and hack around with the codes and you can make your own plugins in no time! Happy coding